# Working with openAuthdotnet to create login page like DisQus

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am trying to work with DotNetOpenAuth but unforunately unable to implement it succcessfully. Samples shipped with the package are not working. Can any body point me out the good tutorial which step by step describes how to implement OAuth(for google,facebook, not openId) My target is very high(Create login page like DisQus) but I am stuck at the very first step :)

thanx

Answer (score 0):

Get the samples from http://sf.net/projects/dnoa.  They should work.